# Sequelize search using include

Tags: node.js, electron, sequelize.js

I want to make a query with Sequelize that returns rows which contains what is in a variable using jquery.

**My code:**

```
var db = require('../../config/db')
var City= db.sequelize.import('./models/city')
var District = db.sequelize.import('./models/district')
var Address = db.sequelize.import('./models/address')
var User = db.sequelize.import('./models/user')

Address.belongsTo(District,{foreignKey:'district_id'})
District.belongsTo(City,{foreignKey:'city_id'})
User.belongsTo(Address,{foreignKey:'address_id'})
```

**I want a query like this: (This code is not working)**

When i run a get this error:

" *SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'district.bairro.nome' in 'where clause'* "

```
   var paramsSearch = {
      offset: offset, limit: limit_records,       
      include:[{model:District, include:[{District, include:[{model: City}]}]}],
      where: {      
        [Op.or]: [
         {'users.user_name': db.sequelize.where(db.sequelize.fn('LOWER', db.sequelize.col('users.user_name')), 'LIKE', '%' + search + '%')},
         {'address.name': db.sequelize.where(db.sequelize.fn('LOWER', db.sequelize.col('address.name')), 'LIKE', '%' + search + '%')},
         {'address.district.name': db.sequelize.where(db.sequelize.fn('LOWER', db.sequelize.col('addrress.district.name')), 'LIKE', '%' + search + '%')}
        ]
      }   
    }

    Cliente.findAll(paramsSearch)
                .then(results=>{
                    console.log(results) 
                }
```

***Someone can help me ?***

Comment: Expalin the `models` and the columns in it and Provide a detailed view of your expected result.

Comment: The city have (name, id)  the district have (id, name, city_fk) and the address have(id, name, district_fk). and also have the user (id, name, address_fk ).

Comment: and I need to search using the city name, the address name, district name all this using th address_id and inner join. Undestant ?

Comment: Can you add your models as well? It would give us better idea

Comment: Also, why are you including `district` in `district`

Comment: I solved my problem changing the name of rows... adding a prefix : table_name